# childSnapshot.getKey(); is retrieving all the key instead of just one (the one that I choose)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling to extract only the key of the selected item from the RecyclerView and then update the value or node associated with that key. The current implementation functions properly when the reservationName is different, such as in the case of "Wedding." However, it encounters issues when there are multiple keys or reservations in that reservationName. Specifically, if I attempt to set or cancel a reservation (Baptism), the operation affects the status of all reservations (Baptism) or keys, rather than just the one I have chosen from the list item.

RecyclerView List Example. I have a date picker for reschedule, even tho I choose the first one, it will show a two date picker. First, the first date picker will update the second one, and then the second date picker will update the first one. It's the same to all function like cancel, pay, reschedule or setting status:

[image]

This is my firebase structure:

[image]

An example code that I use to work in the reservations. I used a toast to retrieve keys and then it shows all the key:

```
private void cancelReservation(Reservation reservation) {
    DatabaseReference reservationRef = reservationsRef.child(reservation.getName());

    reservationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = childSnapshot.getKey();
                    if (childSnapshot.hasChild("status")) {
                        String status = childSnapshot.child("status").getValue(String.class);

                        if (status != null) {
                            //set status to "Cancelled"
                            //alert dialog
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListofReserve.this);
                            builder.setTitle("Cancel Reservation");
                            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel this reservation?");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                             if (status.equals("Cancelled")) {
                                 Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Reservation already cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             } else {
                                 DatabaseReference specificReservationRef = reservationsRef
                                         .child(reservation.getName())
                                         .child(key);

                                 specificReservationRef.child("status").setValue("Cancelled")
                                         .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                             if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                 Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Reservation Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                             } else {
                                                 Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Failed to cancel reservation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                             }
                                         });
                             }
                            });
                            builder.setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> {
                                Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, " " + key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            });
                            builder.create().show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Status not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Reservation not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Error fetching data: " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

You might need the implementation of the RecyclerView:

```
private class ReservationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReservationAdapter.ReservationViewHolder> {

    private List<Reservation> reservations;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;

    public ReservationAdapter(List<Reservation> reservations, ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher) {
        this.reservations = reservations;
        this.activityResultLauncher = activityResultLauncher;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReservationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.reservation_item, parent, false);
        return new ReservationViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReservationViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Reservation reservation = reservations.get(position);
        holder.reservationName.setText(reservation.getName());
        holder.reservationStatus.setText("Status: " + reservation.getStatus());
        holder.reservationDate.setText("Date of Reservation: " + reservation.getDate());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //show a dialog with options to cancel or reschedule
            showReservationOptionsDialog(reservation);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why are looping through all results if you only need one node? Can you please explain what is the exact node you want to get?

Comment: I appreciate the comment. For example, there are 5 reservations name; Baptism, Wedding, Communions, Confirmation & Requiem. In the Recycler list there are 2 Baptism & 1 Wedding.

Comment: If ever I wanted to change something with the A Baptism, it will also affect the other B Baptism, instead of just updating the A Baptism.

Comment: Only updating other Reservation like the Wedding doesn't affect other Reservation like Baptism, Confirmation.

Comment: Then why not create a reference that points only to `A Baptism` and make the change?

Comment: That's actually my problem. I cannot retrieve the key of that A Baptism, instead, it will retrieve all of the Baptism (keys).

Comment: Why do you say you cannot retrieve the key, there is a method that does that. Have you tried using [DataSnapshot#getKey()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getKey())?

Comment: I can but it will retrieve all the keys instead of just the key of the item that I choose in the list. Users>uid>Baptism/Wedding/Communion>key

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching all children of the reservation with name "Baptims" and changing each status, you should get the exact child only by name or id change only the status of that child. Something like this

```
    private void cancelReservation(Reservation reservation) {
        DatabaseReference reservationRef = reservationsRef.child(reservation.getName());

        reservationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                   DataSnapshot childSnapshot = dataSnapshot.getChild(reserveation.id) // somehow get the exact child, can't write exact code as do not know how your object are constructed
     
    String key = childSnapshot.getKey();
                        if (childSnapshot.hasChild("status")) {
                            String status = childSnapshot.child("status").getValue(String.class);

                            if (status != null) {
                                //set status to "Cancelled"
                                //alert dialog
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListofReserve.this);
                                builder.setTitle("Cancel Reservation");
                                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel this reservation?");
                                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                                 if (status.equals("Cancelled")) {
                                     Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Reservation already cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 } else {
                                     DatabaseReference specificReservationRef = reservationsRef
                                             .child(reservation.getName())
                                             .child(key);

                                     specificReservationRef.child("status").setValue("Cancelled")
                                             .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                     Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Reservation Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                 } else {
                                                     Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Failed to cancel reservation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                 }
                                             });
                                 }
                                });
                                builder.setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, " " + key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                });
                                builder.create().show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Status not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                        }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Reservation not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ListofReserve.this, "Error fetching data: " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll try this one later and will update you. I can also give you the structure of the nodes in my code.

Comment: Have you tried it? It works? @KatufoPrem

Comment: A bit of yes, but you help me remove the unnecessary line like the "for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {" which retrieve all the keys in all reservations. Just like your code, I manage to work it by adding 'dataSnapshot.child(reservation.getKey());'

Thanks. Appreciated it!